# Safari displays some letters in custom fonts incorrectly

Tags: next.js, fonts, safari

I have a problem with a custom fonts that are imported via @font-face on NextJS project. I have these fonts both on otf and woff2 formats. On google chrome and Firefox everything works fine (romanianian and czech special letters) but on Safari some of them using fallback to custom font.

Im using 2 fonts: Font Sans, Font Regular and thats the way I'm importing this.

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: Font Sans;
    font-display: swap;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    src: url('./font-sans.woff2') format('woff2');
}
```

I've also tried to import both of them like:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: Font Regular;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-display: swap;
    src: url('./Font-regular.woff2') format('woff2');
    src: url('./Font-Regular.otf') format('opentype');
}
```

When I'm importing both of them, on Safari it doesnt work at all, it just displaying fallback on every letter.

Did you have similar problem? What can I change to fix this?

Comment: font-family names with whitespace characters need to be wrapped in quotes. Quite likely you see a local copy of the font in firefox/chrome and not the webfont version. Also Check your devtools network tab to see if font files are loaded. Also change the src property to `src: url('./Font-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('./Font-Regular.otf') format('opentype');` Currently you're overwriting the first src (woff2) by the otf path.